# PHP/Linux File Permissions

Tags: php

May I ask a question about file permission.
I set up Ubuntu server where Apache got running. I have simple php upload form and able to upload file to /var/www/site/uploads as follows.

```
sandbox@sandbox-virtual-machine:/var/www/site/uploads$ ll
total 1736
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 18 02:53 ./
drwxrwxrwx 3 sandbox  sandbox     4096 Oct 18 00:42 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  145998 Oct 18 02:53 3d wallpaper pic.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  166947 Oct 18 02:53 3D Wallpapers 9.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1451489 Oct 18 02:53  
 6453_3d_landscape_hd_wallpapers_green.jpg
```

Is  there anyway to upload files and they show up as

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 sandbox sandbox  145998 Oct 18 02:53 3d wallpaper pic.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 sandbox sandbox  166947 Oct 18 02:53 3D Wallpapers 9.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 sandbox sandbox 1451489 Oct 18 02:53     
 6453_3d_landscape_hd_wallpapers_green.jpg
```

so that I could straight away feed them to waiting/running shell script.
Right now waiting script(move,checksums,rename,resize,etc) unable to do anything to uploaded files with attributes of www-data.
If I just do as local account, such as

```
sandbox@sandbox-virtual-machine:/var/www/site/uploads$touch testfile
```

then the script is able to run as I would like to.
Any suggestion would be grateful,thanks in advance as well.

Thanks for everyone giving help to me,that I was able to progress.

Now I am close to getting solved and append the output

```
sandbox@sandbox-virtual-machine:/var/www/site/uploads$ ll
total 388
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data   4096 Oct 18 04:22 ./
drwxrwxrwx 3 sandbox  sandbox    4096 Oct 18 04:17 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 sandbox  sandbox  166947 Oct 18 04:21 3D Wallpapers 9.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 sandbox  sandbox  219808 Oct 18 04:20 adafruit_pi.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sandbox  sandbox       0 Oct 18 04:22 test
```

How may I set permission to uploaded files like  'test' only w difference in middle group.
Such as adafruit_pi.png Vs test. Which statement shall I insert to php code,please?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is running as a webapp under apache and that is the `www-data` user that you are seeing.

After upload you can change the owner and group of the files with:

```
exec( 'chgrp sandbox 3*.jpg' );
exec( 'chown sandbox 3*.jpg' );
```

Be aware that after changing permissions, the webserver will not be able to write to the files, or delete or move them.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `chown sandbox:sandbox 3*.jpg` to combine chown and chgrp

Comment: Thanks GlaciesofPacis, how can I edit php to get [ -rw-r--r-- 1   sandbox  sandbox  219808 Oct 18 04:20 adafruit_pi.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sandbox  sandbox       0 Oct 18 04:22 test ] ie make the uploaded file's permission same as test file. I think I am away from only one 'w' in the middle. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding user www-data to the sandbox group

Comment: Thank you for help as well,Ertunc. I did tried earlier but could not able to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the user and group for the apache service: Search in the apache configuration file (I think in ubuntu is located in /etc/apache2/apache2.ini) and search for the lines:

```
User www-data
Group www-data
```

and change `www-data` to `sandbox`.

Notice that the `sandbox` user should have permissions to Read/Write on the webroot folder.

Hope it helps.

**NOTE:This should be implemented for testing purposes, no recommendable for an production environment.**

Comment: Thank you for helping me,I could not find apache2.ini but edited the envvars file and able to make progress.